# Scroll transparent div over div with background image

Tags: html, css

I got a 100% height and width div, which is got a covered and FIXED background image. after this div, there is another div which should include some text BUT with a transparent background. So when i scroll down, the second div scrolls over the first div (it looks like) BUT the text should be on a transparent div.

`Fiddle:`http://jsfiddle.net/do3mw9ju/2/

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you would want your background image on the `<body>` element so it's actually behind everything rather than scrolling.

However, if you want to keep things how they are, you could use a pseudo element for this.

http://jsfiddle.net/do3mw9ju/3/

```
#uberuns {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background:rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
    position:relative;
}
#uberuns:after {
    content:'';
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background: url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c4/PM5544_with_non-PAL_signals.png");
    position:absolute;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-size:cover;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do `<div class="section" id="home"><br><br><br><br></div>` is bad. Use margin/padding to make this spaces, not `<br>`.

For the white div, just use RGBA

http://jsfiddle.net/12p1g2zo/